# Is it possible to supply an image as a camera feed in OSX?

Tags: camera, isight

Is it possible to replace the video feed that my iSight camera gives to a process with a still image, a movie, or an animated gif?

I've seen some apps do this, b

Comment: What's stopping you from using some of those apps you've seen do this?

Comment: I'd like to be able to use that functionality on *any* app. I use some proprietary software for video conferencing. Useful to replace my camera with an image once in a while.

Answer (score -2):

Many apps can do this. A google search for "webcam image replace mac" came up with tons of results, including [ManyCam](http://download.manycam.com/?os=mac).